# Iterating through links for crawler

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm making a crawler with puppeteer in JavaScript. I am having troubles iterating through and crawl on the links I initially crawled.

Here's my crawl function

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function crawl(website){
  let links = [];

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(arguments[0]);

    const hrefs = await page.$$eval("a", (list) => list.map((elm) => elm.href));
    for (let i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
      links.push(hrefs[i]);
    }

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  return links;
};
```

I need help crawling through the links I initially crawled first. Then keep going until I reach some sort of end, then continue onto the next. This is really complex for me and I don't know what to try.

Comment: Push them onto a stack or queue or use recursion to explore the children of each page down to a certain depth.

Answer (score 0):

I deduce from the statement, that you also want to navigate internally between the links that you find during the pages, and I assume you're not interested in knowing the parents of the links (if so, this answer won't help you much).. This code should work.

***The crawl function:***

```
async function crawl(website){
   let links = [];
     try {
       const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
       const page = await browser.newPage();
       await page.goto(website);

       const hrefs = await page.$$eval("a", (list) => list.map((elm) => elm.href));
       for (let i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
         let unique_link = hrefs[i];
         if(hrefs[i].includes("#")){
           unique_link = hrefs[i].split("#")[0]; //Remove the "#" of a link (identifiers in url)
         }
         links.push(unique_link);
       }

       await browser.close();
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(`=> Error on ${website} (Probably an invalid link or dont have any link)`)
     }

     console.log("Running =>", links); //This console log should have all the links of the current page
     return links;
};
```

***The main function and the call***

```
async function main(){
  let all_links = ["https://example.com"];
  let done = [];

  while(all_links.length > 0){
    if(done.includes(all_links[0])){ //To avoid a loop in the links
      all_links.shift();
    } else {
      let links = await crawl(all_links[0]);
      all_links = [...all_links, ...links];

      done.push(all_links[0]);
      all_links.shift();
    }
  }

  console.log("Finished:", all_links); //This should be empty
  console.log("Finished:", done); //This should be filled with all the links crawled
}

main();
```

**CAUTION:**
As I mentioned, this code navigates between all the links found by the function, I didn't change that. So, be careful because it can possibly index links from domains that are probably not relevant (like social networks and etc) and this can cause the code to run "eternally" (it happened when I decided to test). You can build some filters inside the function.